# Floating Point INF/INF

Tags: point, nan, floating, divide

So I know that mathematically infinity/infinity = NAN.  My question is, how does the computer come to this result?  infinity is represented by 7F800000.  So from a computers perspective, 7F800000/7F800000 should be 1.  Does the computer know that it's dealing with infinity numbers and automatically outputs NAN as the result?

Comment: Please have a look at <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN>

Comment: and this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point. floating point operations are not that simple